# How to adjust the location of a label created with annotate to stay inside the frame of a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the annotate option in matplotlib in order to create labels for the markers i have in my plot.
The problem is with the points that are near the edge of the plot, the label runs out of the frame and you can't see what is written in it.

This how i defined the annotate:

```py
self.tooltip = self.canvas.ax.annotate(self.tooltip_text, self.tooltip_coords, xytext=(20, 20),
                                               textcoords="offset points",
                                               size=8, bbox=dict(facecolor='yellow', boxstyle="round"),
                                               arrowprops=dict(shrink=0.05, facecolor='black', width=3, headlength=8))
```

I'm starting my annotate in one method, but update it in another:

```py
    def on_hover(self, event):
        if event.inaxes == self.canvas.ax:
            for line in self.canvas.ax.lines:
                contains, index = line.contains(event)
                if contains:
                    self.tooltip.set_text(line.get_label())
                    self.tooltip.set_x(line.get_xdata())
                    self.tooltip.set_y(line.get_ydata())
                    self.tooltip.set_visible(True)
                    self.tooltip_coords = line.get_xdata(), line.get_ydata()
                    self.tooltip_text = line.get_label()
                    break
            else:
                self.tooltip.set_visible(False)
        self.tooltip_visible = self.tooltip._visible
        # redraw the canvas to display or hide the label
        self.canvas.draw()
```

I would like to know if there is a way to adjust the label so that it stay inside the frame according to the location of the points.

[image: image for example]

Comment: Say `x,y` are your coordinates and `xlim = ax.get_xlim()`. Then if x is larger than `xlim[0]+np.diff(xlim)/2` you would put a minus before the x coordinate of the `xytext` and set `ha="right"`. Else, you put a plus and set `ha="left"`. Same with `y` (and `va`).

Comment: `"top"` or `"bottom"`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest What would be the values for va? for example if the y value is bigger and the minus for the y is when it's bigger or smaller?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I think i'm not really understanding from where i get to coordinates you mentioned in the beggining, because when i create the annotate for what coordinates i have access? and i couldn't figure out when i need to put minus in the y value (when it's bigger or smaller?)

Comment: When the point you want to annotate is in the left half of the figure, you want to position the annotation towards the right of that point; when the annotation is in the right half of the figure, you want to position the annotation to the left of that point (similar for the vertical direction). This ensures that it will always stay within the figure.

Comment: I updated my question because the first code is just the starting of the annotate, the coords are being setting only later, in the on hover method. So if i try the condition i mentioned i'm just getting the label in the middle of the point